# Connection error between server client OS error

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I am pretty much new to socket and I was trying to make a connection inside my local computer using socket.
this is the server

```
import socket

def server():
  host = socket.gethostname()   # get local machine name
  port = 8080  # Make sure it's within the > 1024 $$ <65535 range

  s = socket.socket()
  s.bind(('192.168.56.1', port))

  s.listen(1)
  client_socket, adress = s.accept()
  print("Connection from: " + str(adress))
  while True:
    data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    if not data:
      breakpoint
    print('From online user: ' + data)
    data = data.upper()
    s.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
  s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server()
```

**and this is the client**

```
import socket


def client():
  host = socket.gethostname()  # get local machine name
  port = 8080  # Make sure it's within the > 1024 $$ <65535 range

  s = socket.socket()
  s.connect(("192.168.56.1", port))

  message = input('-> ')
  while message != 'q':
    s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
    data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print('Received from server: ' + data)
    message = input('==> ')
  s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  client()
```

**I know there are useless lines in there but I will clean it up after I finish my connection .**

Comment: Where's the stack trace? What was the error?

Comment: sorry the error is

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thomas Basoglou\Desktop\server.py", line 23, in <module>
    server()
  File "C:\Users\Thomas Basoglou\Desktop\server.py", line 14, in server
    data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied